# jQuery filter is case sensitive - How I disable it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the `jQuery.extend` filter for filtering items. When i use `*` for filtering, it is a problem, because the filter is case sensitive.

`*People` and `*people` are two different strings.

`People` and `people` filtered same items, but only when starting on this string.

How I disable case sensitivity for strings which start with `*`?

Comment: I think you need to make this question clearer. Which part(s) of the selector syntax are you talking about? Perhaps give an example of some HTML and the associated jQuery code.

Comment: How about you show us some code so we have a test case to work with.

Answer (score 2):

You should standardize on casing in your application; I prefer using camelCase.  IE treats "People" and "people" as identical.  Therefore, if you use those as `id`s then you may not even get the element you wanted.  Also, when those strings are used for class names, the second will overwrite the first in IE.  Other browsers follow the standard, and case matters.  For that reason, it should also matter in jQuery.

That answer is making a lot of assumptions with your question.  If you edit it, then I can better help you.